# How can I get an attached eml file from email message content using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, imaplib

I am using python 3.7 and the email, imap library to read email and extract the content of email and attachments , all the attachment ( like excel, csv, pdf) is downloading as attachment but when i received any .eml file in email , it shows me error, please find the below code to read email content and attachment with error showing in case of eml file is received as attachment.
it is showing error at the time of writing eml file.
at the time of write part.get_payload(decode=True) is coming blank in eml file case.

```py
filename = part.get_filename()
if filename is not None:
    dot_position = filename.find('.')
    file_prefix = filename[0:dot_position]
    file_suffix = filename[dot_position:len(filename)]
    # print(dot_position)
    # print(file_prefix)
    # print(file_suffix)
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    timestamp = str(now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f"))
    newFileName = file_prefix + "_" + timestamp + file_suffix
    sv_path = os.path.join(svdir, newFileName)
    # allfiles = allfiles.append([{"oldfilename": filename, "newfilename": newFileName}])
    mydict = filename + '$$' + newFileName
    mydict1 = mydict1 + ',' + mydict
    print(mydict1)
    if not os.path.isfile(sv_path):
        print("oldpath:---->" + sv_path)
        # filename = os.rename(filename, filename + '_Rahul')
        # sv_path = os.path.join(svdir, filename)
        # print("Newpath:---->" + sv_path)
        fp = open(sv_path, 'wb')
        # print("Rahul")
        print(part.get_payload(decode=True))
        # try:
        # newFileByteArray = bytearray(fp)
        # if part.get_payload(decode=True) is not None:
        fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
        # except (TypeError, IOError):
        #    pass
        fp.close()
```

Error is

```
<class 'TypeError'> ReadEmailUsingIMAP.py 129
a bytes-like object is required, not 'NoneType'
```

Comment: What line in your code is generating that error message?

Comment: fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True)) , it is showing error at the time of writing .eml file get_payload is coming None..

Comment: Can you provide all the necessary code and data so that we may run your program? Please see: [mcve].

Comment: @RahulGour at least, what is `part`, `svdir` and `mydict1`?

Comment: Can you also post the full output (including output from print statements and full stack trace?)

Comment: You can use `os.path.splitext` to get the filename and extension of a file. You need to split in the last dot, not the first one [Python 3: os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to explain why this is happening (it hit me too), quoting the v. 3.5 library doc. (v2 says the same):

> If the message is a multipart and the decode flag is True, then None is returned.

If your attachment is an .EML, it's almost always going to be multi-part, thus the None.

Jin Thakur's workaround is appropriate if you're only expecting .EML multipart attachments (not sure if there is any other use cases); it should have been accepted as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use eml_parser
https://pypi.org/project/eml-parser/
    import datetime
    import json
    import eml_parser

```
def json_serial(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime):
        serial = obj.isoformat()
        return serial


with open('sample.eml', 'rb') as fhdl:
    raw_email = fhdl.read()

parsed_eml = eml_parser.eml_parser.decode_email_b(raw_email)

print(json.dumps(parsed_eml, default=json_serial))
```